# How to provide native user interfaces on both Windows and Mac?

Tags: c++, objective-c, windows, macos

I know it's possible to write your code in C++ and use Objective C to make native Mac UI and Visual C++ to make native Windows UI.

Can someone please point me to a tutorial or write a sample code that teaches how to do this?

### NOTE

I know about Qt or wxWidgets but that isn't the solution I want. I really really want to give a native feeling.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Although you say you know about Qt and wxWidgets, I still recommend you use them. You can do native-feeling apps with them.

You will always have to implement some kind of abstraction layer since the Windows and Mac are vastly different in how their UIs are implemented. You would need to find common patterns, find ways on how to abstract things so that different things can be accessed in a similar way. For this, you need to know both Windows and Mac programming very well. You will spend a lot of time trying to find workarounds and searching bugs. With every new iteration of Windows or Mac OS X, you would need to start working around bugs and/or integrating new behavior yet again.

Using a cross-platform library will save you lots of time and trouble and thus money, if you're writing a commercial application.

**Edit:** Well, if you're forced to go that route, I'd recommend to do it like this:

Separate the app into two parts: a backend that doesn't know anything about UI which does all the business logic and then the UI part. You would need to implement the UIs completely separate from each other and wouldn't be able to share much code between them. After all, if you would try to find common grounds (for example, if you would like to unify creating and using a button) you could as well use a cross-platform UI library again...

The upside would be that you could use every obscure UI feature available to each OS. The downside would be that you need to maintain two UIs, so if you add a feature to one UI you'd need to reimplement it in the other as well.

But you might want use a cross-platform library for the backend to unify things like file handling, networking and threading.

Comment: you are right about the pains of going down this path. However my boss is convinced the os specific and native look is what they need and we need to do it. Hence the question.

Comment: Well, if your boss is aware of the additional costs and risks... he's the one paying, so he's the one to decide ;-) But you should sit down together and evaluate what it really is that you're trying to accomplish and whether it really is crucial to have a 100% native UI. That is: are the additional costs and project risks justified? After all, with libraries like Qt you get a very close match (since it's using the native UIs these days) and can have commercial support. Have a look at [Qt in Use](http://qt.nokia.com/qt-in-use). If you do have to implement it yourself, see my updated answer.

Comment: can I write the backend in Qt and use Objective-C for it's UI? and the same thing for Windows?

Comment: Yes, you can do that. You might need some glue classes in Objective-C++ (which allows you to mix C++ and Objective-C), but you'd need that anyway if you're doing the backend with C++. You would simply not use Qt's UI libraries.